# Get all elements inside iframe tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> this is my part of code now i'm using iframe tag and loaded epub on iframe tag
>   then i don't know how to get all elements inside iframe tag.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var tmp = $('#epub_loader iframe').contents().find('body').html();
  alert(tmp);
});
```

```html
<iframe id="epub_loader" href="test.epub" ></iframe>
```

`

Comment: `document.getElementById('epub_loader').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: thanks Vineet but after run your script will give to some Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both your frames are on the same domain and there is [no restriction with Same Domain Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), you can use the following code from the "parent" frame to get an element in the "child" iframe (in your case `body` tag).

Pseudo code, you need to actually point to your iframe DOM by id:

```
var html = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

Notes: In case iframe is on a different domain, you have limited access for browser security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need is to wait document will be fully loaded coz you are used `iframe`,then you should call ....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  window.onload = function () {  //call when iframe is fully loaded
  var tmp = $('#epub_loader').contents().find('body').html();
  alert(tmp);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe is of same origin

```
document.all - HTML collection
document.scripts - Scripts collection
document.styleSheets - CSS Collection
```

Whole HTML Collection

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

[image]